# Ingress traffic route to specific pod endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a go application in K8S and need to configure Ingress for specific endpoint.
Example: when user type in browser xx.yy.com, ingress route this traffic to pod /v1/example endpoint.

How can I do with Ingress or any different method for it ?

Comment: If you're using Nginx as an ingress controller, you can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation in the ingress resource

Comment: @kornshell93 thats not I want.
I want to for example when traffic coming to ingress Path /example, route to pod specific endpoint 
Example:
-  pod_ip:pod_port/v1/api/example

Comment: but that's exactly what `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` allows you to do (except for the port), e.g.: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/$2`, that would redirect the traffic defined under paths in the ingress resource `- path: /example(/|$)(.*)`.

Comment: @kornshell93  could you put your comment as an answer ?

Comment: @Leo I just did

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation in the ingress resource